# Removing anything but number with or without minus sign in R

Tags: regex, r, data-manipulation

We have a column having values like  233 CA, -124 KZ, 231 CA , 2,341 CA, 300KZ .

We just need to add all numbers with or without minus sign.

Here we want output : 2981 
  (that is 233 -124 +231 +2341 +300)

Comment: Can you post the head of your data? Are the values in the same row together, are these different column values?

Answer (score 2):

Use Gabor's solution if you want to become an expert. If you want to remain occasional user try:

```
library(DescTools)
x <- c("233 CA", "-124 KZ", "231 CA", "2,341 CA", "300KZ")

sum(StrVal(x, paste = TRUE, as.numeric = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, with a single `gsub` call:

```
vec=c('233 CA', '-124 KZ', '231 CA' , '2,341 CA', '300KZ')

sum(as.numeric(gsub('[[:alpha:]|[:blank:]|,]','',vec)))
#[1] 2981
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time please post valid R code as input. I have done it this time for you in the first line below.

**1) sub/gsub** We remove commas using `gsub` and then match an optional minus followed by digits followed by anything and then replace that with the portion of the regular expression within parentheses.  Finally we convert to numeric and sum:

```
x <- c("233 CA", "-124 KZ", "231 CA", "2,341 CA", "300KZ")

sum(as.numeric(sub("(-?\\d+).*", "\\1", gsub(",", "", x))))
```

giving:

```
[1] 2981
```

Here is a visualization of the first regular expression:

```
(-?\d+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AB9M95XAv6EEtpFO)

**2) strapply**  Using the same input `x`, `strapply` in the gsubfn package solves it with a slightly simpler regular expression.  After removing the commas we match an optional minus followed by digits, convert each such match to numeric and then use `sum` to simplify the results:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(gsub(",", "", x), "-?\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = sum)
```